# Does the display buffer of an operating system still exist when there is no GPU or monitor attached to a PC?

Tags: c++, windows, screen, gpu, monitor

By Display Buffer, i mean the buffer in which the screenshot of the monitor ,i.e. the entire monitor screen, is stored.
I am trying to design a software which continuously captures the screen images and assembles them into a video.
What i want to know is:-
1) Where exactly are the pixels of the image which appears on my monitor stored in my computer(GPU MEMORY, RAM)?
2) Is this image still present when there is no gpu and monitor connected to the PC?

EDIT : I am targeting windows OS.

Comment: How do you know such an image is stored? Which platform are you targetting?

Answer (score 3):

If there is a "display driver" of some sort, then there will be some form of framebuffer (what gets displayed). Exactly what form that takes, and how you access it would be OS dependent. But in most systems, you need at least some form of graphics processor (or display processor - which is basically just the basic part that scans the framebuffer and pulses out the pixels one at a time in sync with the frequency the monitor (or LCD panel on for example a phone) expects them) to actually feed the data to a monitor, and if that doesn't exist, a "display driver" would be pretty pointless. However, there are systems that use network displays (e.g. "Remote Desktop" for Windows), where the display buffer is entirely software driven, so the graphics displayed is calculated using the CPU only, and there is no requirement to have GPU or DP hardware.

Of course, the frame buffer is not necessarily stored "as it appears on screen" - for example, one could store all the green pixels in one "plane", all the red pixels in another "plane", the "blue" in a third plane, and any "alpha" in a fourth plane. Or in groups if 8 x 16 pixels of each colour. Or in a compressed form (e.g. for software usage over "Remote desktop" type connection, one could imagine a "run length encoded" frame buffer).

The most obvious case of "hardware less" display would probably be in a Virtual Machine. Of course, that's not truly hardware less, it's just that the graphics processor itself (or "dislay adapter", which is really a display processor) is entirely software-based, but pretends to be hardware. However, since the display processor is very simple, all the actual frame buffer operations are done in software inside the VM itself, all the display adapter does is keep track of where the frame buffer is and send it out to the "viewer" (typically as a "Remote Desktop", "VNC" or similar network protocol for viewing the display of a "remote" computer).

To answer your specific questions:

1. Yes one of those, most likely, but could be "something else" too. Exactly how the frame buffer is stored is entirely up to the design of the whole system. Without knowing the exact hardware (e.g. MacBook Pro, PC with Graphics card X, embedded system, smart phone type Y, etc) and software combination (Windows, Linux, custom OS=, there is nothing we can say about how it is stored, as there are as many solutions as you can possibly imagine (if you have VERY good imagination, otherwise there are a few more).
2. If there is no monitor connected, certainly - I'm not aware of any system where the frame buffer is disabled due to "no monitor". The electrical signals on the VGA/DVI/HDMI connector are typically turned off to reduce interference signals when the monitor is not connected, but the image is still being generated, and appear instantly if you plug in a monitor. As explained at the top, a frame buffer doesn't require a GPU - it's just easier/faster.